# Get #included header files after including

Tags: c++, c, gcc, clang, c-preprocessor

Say I've two header files `A.hpp` and `B.hpp` and `A.hpp` gets included in the second file via `#include "A.hpp"` statement. Now when distributing the header files, I want another option which includes a single header file `A_B.hpp` which contains exactly the same code as the contents of `A.hpp` pasted over its `#include` statement.

For now I'm manually copy pasting the contents since releases are fewer and the size of files isn't much, but is there an automated way of doing something like this? Something like `command B.hpp > A_B.hpp`

*Another thing to keep in mind*, I don't want other preprocessor things like macro expansions, OS detection specific macros like -

```
#if defined(__unix__) || defined(__unix) || defined(__linux__)
#define OS_LINUX
#elif defined(WIN32) || defined(_WIN32) || defined(_WIN64)
#define OS_WIN
#elif defined(__APPLE__) || defined(__MACH__)
#define OS_MAC
#else
#error Unknown Platform
#endif
```

to get evaluated since they need to be present in the final file. Any other way to do such taks is also welcomed.

Comment: Write a small program to do it, the syntax for `#include` is not that complicated.

Comment: @RichardCritten ofcourse I can and will do that if such feature isn't already present in some compiler's preprocessor.

Comment: *"Now when distributing the header files, I want another option which includes a single header file A_B.hpp which contains exactly the same code as the contents of A.hpp pasted over its #include statement."* Why?

Comment: @BaummitAugen lets say preference :) Also ease of deployment and user friendliness. Other people are doing it too - https://www.sqlite.org/amalgamation.html

Comment: If you only have a few headers, you could solve this slightly differently. Say `A.hpp` has include guard `A_H_INCLUDED_`, then in `B.h`, include A as `#ifndef A_H_INCLUDED_ #include "A.h" #endif`, and so on. Then, you can create the amalgamation by simply copying all of A.h followed by B.h into A_B.h, which is arguably easier than replacing `#include "A.h"` with the contents of the file.

Comment: clang and gcc (and other compilers presumably) have an option '-H' that will list the hierarchy of header files read during the preprocessor stage.  You could probably write a simple script based on the output from that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to write your own script for this.  What you're asking for is far less than what `gcc -E` does (preprocess everything).  Further, it's less than what `cpp -fdirectives-only` does, because you don't want to recurse.  You effectively have a project-specific requirement, and you'll need to write project-specific code for it.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you are looking for the [unifdef](https://linux.die.net/man/1/unifdef) utility.

> Say I've two header files A.hpp and B.hpp and A.hpp gets included in the second file via #include "A.hpp" statement. Now when distributing the header files, I want another option which includes a single header file A_B.hpp which contains exactly the same code as the contents of A.hpp pasted over its #include statement.

Actually, you don't say what `A.hpp` & `B.hpp` are containing (and details are important). They probably are including some *system* headers (like `<stdio.h>` from C standard library, or `<new>` or `<vector>` headers from the C++ standard library).
Then, distributing their preprocessed form (the output of `g++ -C -E b.hpp` ...) is practically useless, because that form then contains some system and compiler specific declarations/definitions, which is *not* portable to another compiler (in practice the `<map>` from GCC 5 is probably not compatible with the `<map>` from GCC 6).

The whole point of standard libraries is that they are normalizing the name of headers (and their *public* interfaces) like `<vector>` or `<stdio.h>`  but not the details of their contents (and *private* implementations). And compilation options (like `-pthread` or `-std=gnu++11` or `-O` ...) may influence on the preprocessed form (notably thru [common predefined macros](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Common-Predefined-Macros.html)).

You might use the [`-H` preprocessor option](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Preprocessor-Options.html) to `g++` to find out what is included (or even play tricks with various `-M`... options).

Perhaps you might want to distribute an amalgamation of your source code (like [SQLite does](https://www.sqlite.org/amalgamation.html)), but that requires some careful design effort.

You could consider using some external preprocessor like [m4](https://www.gnu.org/software/m4/m4.html) or [GPP](https://logological.org/gpp).

<sup>(but it is project-specific, and much less easy than what you think, precisely because of the role of standard headers in your project ones)</sup>